# How to control pinch zoom in, zoom out on a map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, pinch

In my Android app I've a MapActivity where, when zooming the map with two fingers (pinch) it's zooming, but when I lift the fingers it's zooming further. Meaning, if London is centered on the map, when I am zooming London reaches the edges of the screen; when I lift the fingers, it is going out of screen, zooming further. I want it like iOS map app (No further zooming). How can I do this?

I tried the following code but did not work.

```
class MapOvelay extends Overlay {
   boolean moveTouch;
   int i;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
       switch (event.getAction()) {     
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP://when two fingers are lifted
           mapController.setZoom(i);
           i=0;
           break;

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE://when two fingers are moving on map
           i = mapView.getZoomLevel();
           moveTouch = true;
           break;
   .... 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: can you try a test and add the log of events for a pinch to zoom I am guessing there is an ACTION_MOVE registered after an ACTION_POINTER_UP or ACTION_UP

Comment: Did you find the solution? I too facing same issue.

Comment: @Veer No..Its google map behavior.

Comment: Okay, I too checked google map application for 2.2 and it too behave in same way (over-zoom). But if you check google map application for 4.0 works fine. But when we implement our mapview in 4.0 it do over-zoom. So, i think there must be some solution..

Comment: @Veer Try 4.1 Jelly Bean may be there is a solution because of "project Butter" i am not sure..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the zoomToSpan-functionality?

```
mMapController.zoomToSpan(maxLatitude - minLatitude,maxLongitude - minLongitude);
```

Also, you can restrict lowest zoom with something like this

```
if (LOWEST_ZOOM_LEVEL < mMap.getZoomLevel() ) {
    mMapController.setZoom(LOWEST_ZOOM_LEVEL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum zoom level available by calling #getMaxZoomLevel() in your MapView. That's the closest zoom you will be able to get, no matter what happens in the official Google Maps application.
`mapView.getController().animateTo(geoPoint);`
`mapView.getController().setZoom(15);`
`mapView.invalidate();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    mapview.getController().animateTo(startGP);
    mapview.getController().setZoom(13);        
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapview.invalidate();
```